# adding String array into ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I want to append `a` and `b` string arrays to arrayList. But `"1.0"` have to be `"1"` using with split. Split method returns String[] so arrayList add method does not work like this.
Can you suggest any other way to doing this ?

```
String[] a = {"1.0", "2", "3"};
String[] b = {"2.3", "1.0","1"};

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

arrayList.add(a[0].split("."));
```

Comment: what is the expected output, not clear

Comment: `a[0].split(".")[0]`

Comment: just get the first element of the split array

Comment: The argument of ``split()`` is a regular expression, so if you want your delimiter to be ``.``, you have to escape it such that it becomes ``\\.``.

Comment: @Deniz because `.` is splitted using `\\.` in java, refer to answers

Comment: Using `split()` will be an overkill here.. Why create an array of Strings?. Just use `replaceAll()`or even `subString()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
arrayList.add(a[0].split("\\.")[0]);
```

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Comment: Corrected it, faulty regex.

Comment: Firstly thanks, i had exception like this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Answer (score 2):

Should be as below

```
arrayList.add(a[0].split("\\.")[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Split method returns an array. You have to access to his position to get the number.

```
arrayList.add(a[0].split("\\.")[0]);
```

You can also use substring method:

```
arrayList.add(a[0].substring(0, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Access first element of that array like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].contains("."))
        arrayList.add(a[i].split("\\.")[0]);
    else
        arrayList.add(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Why split it?. Just use a `replaceAll()`, it will be more efficient as it won't create an array of Strings.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = { "1.7", "2", "3" };
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        arrayList.add(a[i].replaceFirst("\\..*", "")); // escape the . (match it as a literal), then followed by anything any number of times.
    }
    System.out.println(arrayList);

}

O/P :
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working properly for me:  `arrayList.add(a[0].split("\\.")[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8,

```
String[] a = {"1.0", "2", "3"};

List<String> list = Arrays.stream(a).map(s -> s.split("\\.")[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());

// OR

List<String> list2 = Arrays.stream(a).map(s -> {
  int dotIndex = s.indexOf(".");
  return dotIndex < 0 ? s : s.substring(0, dotIndex);
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```